# How can I delete all events at once in FullCalendar without using getEventsById?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to delete all events from my FullCalendar calendar once I switch view, because when I come back to the same view, it duplicates the items. How can I delete events once I switch, so when I add the event again, it doesnt duplicate?

I am doing an AJAX request when I call the `retrieveData()` function to fetch for events from the server which I then add to the calendar. Everytime I make the call, it adds the event to the calendar, even if it is there from before, hence I want to first delete all events and then add the events. If there is a better way to not duplicate content upon switching view, please let me know. Any help will be deeply appreciated :)

Here is the code to my calendar

***Initiliasing the calendar***

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin],
      initialView: "timeGridWeek",
      headerToolbar : {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      allDaySlot: false,
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      scrollTime: '08:00:00',

    
    });
```

***Calling and defining the `retrieveData()` function where I am making AJAX calls to get the events from the server and add them to the calendar***

```
retrieveData()

  function retrieveData() {
          
          $.ajax({

            method: 'GET',
            url: `${calendarEndpoint}`,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: configData,
            success: function (data) {


              for(var i=0; i<1;i++){

                var event = {
                  title: 'The Title', // a property!
                  start: '2021-05-26T09:00:00', // a property!
                  end: '2021-05-26T11:00:00'
                }
                
                calendar.addEvent(event);

              }

              calendar.render()

            },
            error: function (error) {
              console.log("error here",error);
            }
          })
        };
```

***On clicking the next and previous arrow buttons, the retrieveData() function is called as well***

```
document.getElementById('left-arrow-calendar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calendar.prev();
    

  retrieveData()

  });

document.getElementById('right-arrow-calendar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calendar.next();
    

  retrieveData()

  });
```

***This is how it looks like when I first load the page vs when I go to the next week and then come back to the current week***

[image]

[image]

Comment: `because when I come back to the same view, it duplicates the items`...I suggest trying to fix this issue rather than implement a workaround. I'll elaborate...see below:

Comment: `Everytime I make the call, it adds the event to the calendar, even if it is there from before, hence I want to first delete all events and then add the events` ...you're making a pigs ear of doing something which fullCalendar can already do for you! Use an event source instead of manually adding them one by one, and then fullCalendar will handle this automatically for you - then you won't need to use addEvent, and you won't need to handle the next/prev button clicks (which aren't the only ways the view or date range can change, anyway!).

Comment: There are a couple of approaches: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. Note that in both cases fullCalendar will trigger a new update automatically whenever the view or date range changes and it doesn't already have downloaded dates for the new range. Note also that it expects your server only to return events for the date range it provides in the start and end parameters.

Comment: @ADyson so I do not need to make an AJAX call on my end? Will FullCalendar do that for me?

Comment: If you use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed then fullCalendar generates the AJAX request for you, and sends it to the URL you provide. The only requirements are that your server responds to that request with an array of events in the specific JSON format that fullCalendar requires (e.g. something like `[{ "title": "event1", "start": "2010-01-01" }, { "title": "event2", "start": "2010-01-05", "end": "2010-01-07" }]`) and that it only returns events which start within the date range it provides via the automatically-added start and end parameters.

Comment: If for some reason you cannot make your server code fit in with this requirement, then you can use the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function pattern where you still have code the AJAX request (to your own specification), but you put it inside a callback function which is passed to fullCalendar, so that fullCalendar can call the function (and thus trigger the AJAX) whenever it wants new events. Again it's expected that you ensure it only returns events within the date range supplied to the callback.

Comment: @ADyson alright, thanks! :)